NetworkManager only connects to WiFi when I pass --ask (but it already has the password)
I have a wifi connection defined by NetworkManager on a Raspberry Pi 4, using the latest Rasbian OS (bookworm):
me@hostname:~ $ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my_wifi_ssid.nmconnection
[connection]
id=my_wifi_ssid
uuid=30f65701-8eb3-4986-a61b-26c176087d4b
type=wifi

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=my_wifi_ssid

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=[big long hex string containing wifi password]

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[proxy]
me@hostname:~ $

Now, if I try to bring up this connection with nmcli,  it complains that there was no password given, and it cannot ask me for a password because I didn't pass --ask:
me@hostname:~ $ sudo nmcli conn up my_wifi_ssid
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'my_wifi_ssid'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=30f65701-8eb3-4986-a61b-26c176087d4b + NM_DEVICE=wlan0' to get more details.

However, if I allow nmcli to ask me for a password, it works, and (usually) doesn't ask me:
me@hostname:~ $ sudo nmcli conn up my_wifi_ssid --ask
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/44)

I have seen behavior before where it did ask me; in that case, the password is pre-filled, and if I simply hit enter, the connection comes up successfully.
What gives?
